# How do I get MessageBox button caption?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, messagebox

I'm making a custom message box that lets you copy text, but I wanted it to look exactly like a standard message box, so I would like to set the buttons text to whatever the system language is, as the MessageBox class does.
Does anyone knows how to get that text ("Yes", "No", "Cancel", etc)?.

Comment: If you don't find a solution, perhaps you can put the message text on the clipboard instead and inform the user the message is on the clipboard.

Comment: If you press Ctrl+C when a standard MessageBox is shown, it will copy the text to the clipboard by default.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but anyway I need more customization like scroll bars for bigger messages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for your answers with Snarfblam link I could figure out the rest.

```
class Program {

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, uint uID, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nBufferMax);
[DllImport("kernel32")]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

private const uint OK_CAPTION = 800;
private const uint CANCEL_CAPTION = 801;
private const uint ABORT_CAPTION = 802;
private const uint RETRY_CAPTION = 803;
private const uint IGNORE_CAPTION = 804;
private const uint YES_CAPTION = 805;
private const uint NO_CAPTION = 806;
private const uint CLOSE_CAPTION = 807;
private const uint HELP_CAPTION = 808;
private const uint TRYAGAIN_CAPTION = 809;
private const uint CONTINUE_CAPTION = 810;

static void Main(string[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);

    IntPtr user32 = LoadLibrary(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\User32.dll");

    LoadString(user32, OK_CAPTION, sb, sb.Capacity);
    string ok = sb.ToString();

    LoadString(user32, CANCEL_CAPTION, sb, sb.Capacity);
    string cancel = sb.ToString();

    LoadString(user32, ABORT_CAPTION, sb, sb.Capacity);
    string abort = sb.ToString();

    LoadString(user32, RETRY_CAPTION, sb, sb.Capacity);
    string retry = sb.ToString();

    LoadString(user32, IGNORE_CAPTION, sb, sb.Capacity);
    string ignore = sb.ToString();

    LoadString(user32, YES_CAPTION, sb, sb.Capacity);
    string yes = sb.ToString();

    LoadString(user32, NO_CAPTION, sb, sb.Capacity);
    string no = sb.ToString();

    LoadString(user32, CLOSE_CAPTION, sb, sb.Capacity);
    string close = sb.ToString();

    LoadString(user32, HELP_CAPTION, sb, sb.Capacity);
    string help = sb.ToString();

    LoadString(user32, TRYAGAIN_CAPTION, sb, sb.Capacity);
    string tryAgain = sb.ToString();

    LoadString(user32, CONTINUE_CAPTION, sb, sb.Capacity);
    string cont = sb.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

These strings appear to be stored in the User32.dll library. There are details in [this discussion](http://www.purebasic.fr/english/viewtopic.php?t=24134&sid=cf59f7045f38869cb347d09ad9e73f6e) on the Pure BASIC forum, towards the bottom.

Comment: Thank you very much with that I could find the solution, I will post the code in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You might open the System.Windows.Forms.dll in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and see how it is setting the button text.

Comment: I did that, but the message box call is a function in user32.dll so the text is obtained in low level, I'm sure there is an api to get it.

Answer (score -1):

In the time you typed that message, you could have typed "Yes", "No", "Ok", "Cancel"...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP wants to take the text from the system so that it's in the correct language (system locale)

Comment: Exactly Adam, that's what I need so I don't have to exhaust all languages